# Getting a bug in word file after mailmerge

Tags: excel, mailmerge

I've inserted a command button in my word file for creating a doc and a pdf file after pressing the command button. Command button is working doc and pdf file are creating but after completing I'm getting 4198 error.

The file path where the doc and pdf file should be save is coming from mail merge.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim masterDoc As Document, singleDoc As Document, lastRecordNum As Integer

    Set masterDoc = ActiveDocument

    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
    lastRecordNum = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord

    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord

    Do While lastRecordNum > 0

        masterDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        masterDoc.MailMerge.Execute False

        Set singleDoc = ActiveDocument

        singleDoc.SaveAs2 _
            FileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
                masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFileName").Value & ".docx", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

        singleDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            OutputFileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
                masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFileName").Value & ".pdf", _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

        singleDoc.Close False

        If masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord >= lastRecordNum Then
            lastRecordNum = 0
        Else
            masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
        End If

    Loop
End Sub
```